# Applying p html-tag at return key press in textarea with Rails5

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, textarea, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I have a textarea input for people to write a very basic description and this description can be in paragraphs. Currently when user hits return (enter) key, it doesn't create new paragraph unless user writes

HTML tags manually. But not all users know html-tags. How can I apply that as default when user hits return key.

I'm using simple_form gem:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @post, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :description, label: "Description:", input_html: { cols: 66, rows: 5, maxlength: 1500 }, as: :text  %>
```

and I use sanitize gem when displaying

```
  <%= Sanitize.fragment(@post.description, Sanitize::Config::BASIC).html_safe %>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a markdown parser like [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) when rendering the `@post.description`. That's how I've handled this kind of thing in the past.

After you install redcarpet according to the docs, create a helper method like this (adjusting as necessary):

```
def markdown(text)
  return "" unless text.present?
  options = {
    filter_html:     true,
    hard_wrap:       true,
    link_attributes: { rel: 'nofollow', target: "_blank" },
    space_after_headers: true,
    fenced_code_blocks: true
  }

  extensions = {
    autolink:           true,
    superscript:        true,
    disable_indented_code_blocks: true
  }

  renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(options)
  markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)

  markdown.render(text).html_safe
end
```

Then you can use this in your view `<%= markdown(@post.description) %>` to render the description how you want.